# Scroll three GridViews simultaneously

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to put three or even four `GridView` in one layout and scroll them simultaneously.

Since `GridView` has own `ScrollView`'s widget, I need to disable that `ScrollView` via `android:isScrollContainer="false"` property and override `GrideView` measure to have `wrap_content` functionality, here is my extended GrideView:

```
public class ExpandedGridView extends GridView
{
    public ExpandedGridView (Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandedGridView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public gridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // But do not use the highest 2 bits of this integer; those are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode.
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

It's working, but it's disable some `BaseAdapter`'s servitors like recycling, reuses and so on..., So that's make my `GridView` slowly in scrolling and it's not smooth enough!

Any idea about how to make it faster?

**Update 1: added my `GridAdapter` class:**

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{   
    private Context c;
    private DisplayImageOptions mOptions;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private String[] appIconUri, appName, appPrice, appRate;

    public GridAdapter(Context c, String[] appIconUri, String[] appName
            , String[] appPrice, String[] appRate) 
    {
        this.appIconUri = appIconUri;
        this.appName = appName;
        this.appPrice = appPrice;
        this.appRate = appRate;
        this.c = c;

        // Setup ImageLoader
        this.mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        this.mOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.border)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.border)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .resetViewBeforeLoading()
            .cacheOnDisc() 
            .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(750))
            .build();

        if (!mImageLoader.isInited())
        {
            ImageLoaderConfiguration mImageLoaderConfiguration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c)
                .threadPoolSize(2) 
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .build();
            mImageLoader.init(mImageLoaderConfiguration);
        }
    }

    public ImageLoader getCurrentImageLoader()
    {
        return mImageLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return appName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int itemData) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int itemPosition) 
    {
        return itemPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {       
       ViewHolder mViewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = ((Activity) c).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_list, null);

            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            mViewHolder.lblName = (textView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appName);
            mViewHolder.lblPrice = (textView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appPrice);
            mViewHolder.rtbRate = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appRate);
            mViewHolder.imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);

            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        }
        else
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        mViewHolder.lblName.setText(appName[position]);

        // This line should be changed
        mViewHolder.lblPrice.setText((Integer.valueOf(appPrice[position]) == 0) ? "مجانی" : appPrice[position]);

        mViewHolder.lblPrice.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        mViewHolder.rtbRate.setRating(appRate[position] != null ? Float.valueOf(appRate[position]) : 0);

        mImageLoader.displayImage(appIconUri[position], mViewHolder.imgIcon, mOptions);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        textView lblName, lblPrice;
        RatingBar rtbRate;
        ImageView imgIcon;
    }
```

Comment: can u show some screenshots of the grids that u r scrolling simultaneously?..i mean, how r dey aligned on the screen?

Comment: it seems odd to me that you need multiple gridviews on screen at once, you might want to reconsider that design in the first place. Can you provide an example you're trying to emulate maybe? you also dont explain why you want to have wrap content work, otherwise you could just try syncing up the on scroll listners.

Comment: @bakriOnFire Please see this link for clarify http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/04/how-to-make-the-height-of-a-gridview-wrap-its-content/

Comment: @Eluvatar Please see this link for clarify http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/04/how-to-make-the-height-of-a-gridview-wrap-its-content/

Comment: You can do this with a simple TableLayout inside a ScrollView too..why do u want to use a gridview and handle its wrap_content explicitly.

Comment: @bakriOnFire if he's trying to display a dynamic amount of content then that's why he would want a grid view with an adapter. As for putting some kind of group header on a gridview like that, I'll post an idea as an answer in a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a quick search I found a library someone's made to do this already http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/ no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's a good solution but my layout also contains some other stuff like `Buttons`, `ViewFlipper` and etc.

Comment: it's just a view, you aren't forced to only use the 1 view. you would use it just like you're trying to use your multiple grids now just replace all of them with of stickyGridHeader view

Comment: Can I put it in ScrollView?

Comment: You could, but shouldn't (you'll have the same performance issues)